# Insert multiple rows into a database table using a loop

Tags: php, module, json

I am trying to insert post data inside a Joomla table. So within a loop I populate the query with the values of a decoded json  but all the time I get this error: **Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

Here is my code:

```
 $columns = array('column1','column2','column3','column4');

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

foreach($arrayDecodedJson as $key => $value)
{
                
    $query
        ->insert($db->quoteName('#__table_name_'))
        ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
        ->values(implode(',', $db->quote($value)));

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $db->execute();
}
```

The ***$value*** is an array with values I want to insert into the already existed table.

The ***$arrayDecodedJson*** keys and the columns are the same.

The data after var_dump($arrayDecodedJson) are like:

> array( 'key1'=>'value1','key2'='value2') , array(
> 'key1'=>'value3','key2='value4'),
> ... array( 'key1'=>'valueN','key2'='value'N)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the other answer works, it's not very efficient. Instead everything but `$query->values()` call can be done outside the loop. This way multiple rows are inserted with a single database query:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true)
    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__table_name_'))
    ->columns($db->quoteName($columns));

foreach($arrayDecodedJson as $row)
{
    $query->values(implode(',', $db->quote($row)));
}

$db->setQuery($query)->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simple.

1. Put ***$query = $db->getQuery(true);***, inside the foreach loop.
2. Make an array in order to put inside the arrays values like :

> ```
> $values = array($db->quote($value['value1']),$db->quote($value['value2']),$db->quote($value['value3']),$db->quote($value['value4'])
> ```

Then you make the query like so inside the foreach loop:

> ```
>               $query
>                   ->insert($db->quoteName('#__table_name'))
>                   ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
>                   ->values(implode(',',$values));
>               $db->setQuery($query);
>               $db->execute();
> ```

I hope that it will help someone!